# What book should I refer for flip flop timing diagram for VLSI (for such question given below)?

Tags: clock, digital, flip-flop, vlsi, timing-diagram

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdg2b.jpg)

I am pursuing masters in electronics system design and this was my question paper for today exam was unable to answers the first three questions properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the one that helped me the most.
https://www.amazon.ca/Digital-Design-Computer-Architecture-Harris/dp/0123944244